# Objective-C UIWebview and UITableView scroll height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview, scroll

I encounter a problem using UIWebView and UITableView in my application. I don't understand why i'm not able to scroll at the bottom of the list : it always missing several points to scroll to the bottom (take a look at the mockup below).

In all my screens I have a fixed label at the top and an UIScrollView or UIWebView or UITableView under I think it's probably the origin of the problem. I tried to update view height or scroll height but it doesn't work...

I've made a mockup to show you what my application screens looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJjh7.jpg
As you can see, the text is truncated at the bottom because I cannot scroll to the bottom...

Anyone help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Scroll in views works but it not let me scroll completly down...

Here is an example of my code :

```
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation ContentController {

- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.windowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
   self.windowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


   // Bandeau titre

   UILabel* titre =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 50)];
   titre.font = FONT_RALEWAY_BOLD(18);
   titre.backgroundColor = MAIN_BLUE;
   titre.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   titre.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   titre.text = @"Test";

   [self.windowView addSubview:titre];

   [self createWebViewWithHTML];
   self.webView.delegate = self;

   [self.windowView addSubview:self.webView];

   self.view = self.windowView;

}


- (void) createWebViewWithHTML{
     NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"<html><head><title></title></head><body style=\"background:transparent; padding:0px; margin:15px 15px;\">"];

    [html appendString: content];

    [html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];

    [self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@APP_IMAGES_DIR];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
}
```

Comment: there is not much information can debug... check scrollView content size; try to set self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; in viewDidLoad

Comment: I think your tableview or webview's height is more than the frame height and hence it's not able to scroll. Try and reduce the height of your tableview...align the height of the view with the window through storyboard or nib.

Comment: «Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.» As UITableView ← UIScrollView, this applies here.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/

Comment: I'm not using storyboard. My UIWebView is implemented into an UIView not in UIScrollView. I have also tried to increase my windowView height to match with UIWebView but without success...

Comment: did you reduce the webview heigth?

Comment: It works ! Thanks for your answer ! You saved me a lot of time ! I will post an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy... Just reduce the height of UIWebView or UITableView if you have fixed content under the navigation bar.

**For UIWebView :**

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT-(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 50))];
```

**For UITableView :**

```
self.tabView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT-(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 50))];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set scrollEnabled to YES if you have not set it already.

And also set the content size. Remember that content size height should be greater than frame height.

If you can paste the code, that will help to give more specific answer